# Можно ли установить `inputType` для клавиатуры в WebView?

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview, uiwebview

В апплекации есть реализация WebView в котором есть поля для заполнения. Так вот вопрос в том, можно ли, чтоб при нажатии юзером на поле с указанием номера телефона открывалась клавиатура с типом `android:inputType="number"` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так

> Создайте подкласс WebView и переопределите метод
>   onCreateInputConnection. Этот метод вызывается при выборе поля ввода в
>   WebView и дает возможность настроить способ обработки события.

```
@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
    BaseInputConnection ic = new BaseInputConnection(this, true);
    outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER; // Tells the keyboard to show the number pad
    return ic;
}
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28845319/5330439)